# How can the Developer Tools browser console return something other than window for "this"?

Tags: javascript, scope, developer-tools

While working on JavaScript projects, I often use the console to check on objects. In the project I'm currently working with I've somehow altered the scope of the console. When I type `this` into the console (in Chrome Developer Tools) after everything loads I get one of the objects. Every other time I've done this (`this`) with other projects and sites (including StackOverflow), I've gotten back the `window` object.

How is it possible that the console's scope can be changed? Also helpful if you have any tips for how to debug this.

Comment: following any pattern like `AMD` or `Commonjs`?

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem was due to a break-point I had in the code within a component. When I was running `this` during the break it was returning the scope from the point of the break-point.

So it seems that the scope of the console changes along with the code execution. Somehow I never noticed this before.

Comment: that would make sense, and make debugging possible